# Inconsistent progress bar on Fine Uploader S3 basic

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I recently switched from Dropzone JS to Fine uploader just because its a much more superior experience and has a lot more working features like chunking, direct S3 support and similar.

Since we have a pretty custom UI i simply used the S3 Basic version of the Fine uploader or s3.fine-uploader.core.min.js if you will. The version is: 5.15.6.

We are having problems with the total progress bar callback and the fact that the progress bar simply in 90% of cases doesn't work as expected. Sometimes it works really great like it shows accurate percentage, does not hang and is consistent. But most of the time it simply jumps from 20% to 100%, does not display gradual progress for large files like 200MB (it shows 5% and then after x amount of time it shows 100%).

I used the debug mode i know it uploading in chunks so it should be getting a gradual progress but i simply don't know what to do anymore.

The back-end to sign S3 requests is Laravel which we use for post processing. The UI aspect is built using Bootstrap 4.

If someone has an idea please i would like to take this off my mind. Thank you.

The JS code is here

```
var dragAndDropModule = new qq.DragAndDrop({
    dropZoneElements: [document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]],
    callbacks: {
        processingDroppedFilesComplete: function(files, dropTarget) {
            uploader.addFiles(files);
        }
    }
});

var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploaderBasic({
    debug: false,
    button: document.getElementById('upload-file'),
    validation: {
        sizeLimit: 5368709120
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    objectProperties: {
        region: 'some region',
        key: function (id) {
            return upload_path + '/'+ uploader.getName(id);
        }
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: 'some endpoint',
        accessKey: 'some key',
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: '/s3/endpoint',
        version: 4,
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    },
    uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: '/files/store',
        customHeaders: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        params: {
            order_id: 'id',
            upload_path: 'path',
            folder_id: 'folder_id',
            type: 'original'
        }
    },
    callbacks: {
        onProgress: function(id, name, totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
            var progress =  Math.round((parseInt(totalUploadedBytes) * 100)/parseInt(totalBytes));
        },
        onTotalProgress: function(totalUploadedBytes, totalBytes) {
            var total_progress =  Math.round((parseInt(totalUploadedBytes) * 100)/parseInt(totalBytes));
            $('.total-upload-progress .progress-bar').width(total_progress + '%');
            $('.total-upload-progress .total-count').html(total_progress + '%');
        },
        onUpload: function(id, name) {
            if($('.total-upload-progress:hidden')) {
                $('.total-upload-progress').show();
            }
        },
        onSubmit: function(id, name) {
            var file_size = this.getSize(id);

            this.setParams({
                size: file_size
            });

            $('.file-list .row').append('<div class="col-md-3"><div class="card" id="file-'+id+'"><div class="card-image"><img src="no-preview.jpg" id="preview-'+id+'" class="img-fluid"><span class="file-status processed">Uploading</span></div><div class="card-body"><h5>File name:</h5><h4>'+name+'</h4></div></div>');

            // LESS THAN 10MB
            if(file_size < 10485760) {
                var image_element = document.getElementById('preview-'+id);
                this.drawThumbnail(id, image_element, 255, false);
            }
        },
        onComplete: function(id, name,responseJSON,xhr) {
            $('#file-'+id).find('.file-status').removeClass('processed').addClass('uploaded').text('Uploaded');
        },
        onError: function(id, name,responseJSON,xhr) {
            $('#file-'+id).find('.file-status').removeClass('processed').addClass('error').text('Error');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It sounds like you're reporting a bug, in which case Stack Overflow is not the proper medium. But even if this was posted in the issue tracker, there's nothing to act on. You'll need to provide information about the actual failure, such as specific reproduction steps.

Comment: Hey Ray, i posted on Stackoverflow because i wanted to see if there is something maybe missing from my code, maybe i forgot a callback or function, maybe i am doing something wrong...

I will try to reproduce it and provide in-depth review once i am sure its not me or my code. Because like i said sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it simply doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question in two words: Service Worker.

Turns out that the service worker i have setup to cache the website and enable offline functionality was affecting the progress bar.